# Check what package provides a debian dependency

Tags: debian, apt, deb

There are some such packages that are not actually available from the repository, but are instead "Provides" provided by other packages.

For example, packages may depend on `libc-dev`, but (at least in my case) `libc-dev` is provided by `libc6-dev`.

Is there way to check which package provides some other package/dependency?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of at the moment is to use `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude search '~Plibc-dev' |head
i  libc6-dev - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
p  libc6-dev-arm64-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-armel-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-armhf-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-hppa-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-m68k-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-mips-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-mips64-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-mips64el-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
p  libc6-dev-mips64r6-cross - GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
$ _
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `apt-cache showpkg` (on ALT and Debian and Ubuntu):

```
root@rx2620:~# apt-cache showpkg libc-dev | tail
    libattr1-dev,libc-dev
    libamu-dev,libc-dev
    libasound2-dev,libc-dev
    libafterimage-dev,libc-dev
    libacl1-dev,libc-dev
Dependencies:
Provides:
Reverse Provides:
    libc6.1-dev 2.13-35
    libc6.1-dev 2.13-38+deb7u10
root@rx2620:~#
```